# Is it correct to use the OAuth URL on href to link to the Google OAuth Login UI

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

Is it correct to directly link the Google OAuth URL **(ex. : https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://myredirecturl.com/login&client_id=xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email+profile&access_type=online&approval_prompt=auto)** generated by the Google libraries on my Sign-In with Google link.

Like currently first the user clicks on my Sign-In with Google button, then user goes to the authurl generator script and then he gets the Google Login button and then again he has to click on the login button to get to the Google Login UI. This is a long process so I had to ask this.

Currently this is my ui flow :

1. user opens my site: mywebsite.com
2. gets the following html :

   ```html
    <html><body>
       
   <div>        <a href="www.mywebsite.com/googlelogin.php">Login with Google</a></div>

     <div>  <a href="www.mywebsite.com/fblogin.php">Login with Facebook</a>
   </div>
   </body></html>
   ```
3. Clicks Login with Google button & reaches again a Login button, **here again the Login button appears & this is the 2nd time the user has to click to Login and then he reaches the GMAIL Login UI ? Why is this process not being done in one click ?**

```html
     <html><body>
        
        <a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://myredirecturl.com/login&client_id=xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email+profile&access_type=online&approval_prompt=auto">Login with Google</a> ---  Here again the Login button comes and this is the second time the user has to click to Login ??? Why is this process not being done in one click??</body></html>
```

**UPDATE:**

**1st STEP / Screen : www.mywebsite.com/index.php**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href="www.mywebsite.com/googlelogin.php">LOGIN WITH GOOGLE</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**2nd STEP / Screen : mywebsite.com/googlelogin.php** , 
**here again a new LOGIN BUTTON is shown on which the user has to click to go to the GMAIL LOGIN UI.**

```
session_start();  


$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setClientId($client_id);

$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);

$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);

$client->addScope("email");

$client->addScope("profile");


//incase of logout request, just unset the session var
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) 
{

    unset($_SESSION['access_token']);

    $client->revokeToken();

    session_destroy();

}



$service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);



if (isset($_GET['code'])) 
{ 

    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

    exit; 

}





    //Set Access Token to make Request

    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) 
    {

        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

    }



    //Get User Data from Google Plus 

    if ($client->getAccessToken()) 
    {

      $userData = $service->userinfo->get();

      $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    } 
    else 
    { 

        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

    }


   **//here comes the 2nd Login Button** 
   **//here comes the 2nd Login Button** 
   **//here comes the 2nd Login Button** 
   **//here comes the 2nd Login Button** 

if (isset($authUrl))
{  

    //show login url 
    echo '<div>Please click login button to connect to Google.</div>';

    echo '<a href="' . $authUrl . '">LOGIN WITH GOOGLE </a>'; 

}
else
{

    $user = $service->userinfo->get(); //get user info 

    echo 'Welcome '.$user->name.'! ';

}
```

Comment: I am not sure i understand the question.   Define fine?  if it works i guess its ok unless you have some specific worry.     btw i dont think you need access_type=online

Comment: @DalmTo : I mean that is it correct to use the URL directly as href  on the Login As Google link...what is the correct process which everyone uses...because my process is making the user click twice on the login button which i guess is wrong

Comment: @DaImTo : I have edited my question. Please guide now.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what the problem is exactly.

Comment: @DalmTo : I want to eliminate an extra click step.

Right now the user has to make 2 clicks in order to login...i want it to be in just SINGLE click, that is, on first click itself the Google GMAIL Login UI should open.

But right now the 2nd page opens which again shows the login button and then on clicking on which the user goes to the GMAIL Login UI.

Comment: @DalmTo : i have  added an update to my post...please check and guide me.....:)

Comment: @DalmTo : I have mentioned the PHP and HTML code for both my PHP  script files for complete reference, would be great if you can just help me out :)

Comment: You should simply _redirect_ the user to that URL - instead of creating a _link_ that the user then has to click manually.

Comment: @CBroe : u mean i shall directly use the AUTHURL in $authurl in the FIRST PAGE LOGIN LINK HREF

Comment: No, I mean you redirect to that URL, in the place where right now you are outputting a link instead.

Comment: @CBroe : ok i will do the same and hope the sessions data also work and am able to complete it....will connect u again if stuck :) :)..thanks a lot CBroe

Comment: @CBroe : also in my further scripts/pages am checking if user is logged in or not by doing this  : if (   isset ($_SESSION['authurl'])   &&  isset($_SESSION['access_token'])   ) {   //logged in } else { //not logged in }  ------------- i hope this check is fine

Comment: @CBroe :   in my subsequent scripts/pages to validate if user is logged in or not by doing this : -------- if ( isset ($_SESSION['authurl']) && isset($_SESSION['access_token']) ) { //logged in } else { //not logged in } ------------- i hope this check is fine – do i need to do some value checks also of access_token or of any variable ???

Comment: @DalmTo :  in my subsequent scripts/pages to validate if user is logged in or not by doing this : --------                                                                   
                        if ( isset ($_SESSION['authurl']) && isset($_SESSION['access_token']) ) { //logged in } else { //not logged in } ------------- i hope this check is fine –  do i need to do some value checks also of access_token or of any variable ???